# Are numeric parameters subject to SQL injection attacks?

Tags: java, sql-injection

Consider this statement:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=?");
stmt.setInt(1, id);
```

The above is considered safe from SQL Injection attacks. Is the one below also safe, knowing that `id` is of type `int`?

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=" + id);
```

If not, what can go wrong?

Comment: There is no SQL injection possible when `id` is in fact of type `int`.

Comment: If `id` is an int, there is no SQL injection possible, just overflow. However hard to check by a reader, and it is a mixture of text and code. Parameterized SQL could be externalized in XML or whatever.

Comment: It's safe, for now. One problem is that someone may decide later that String IDs are more appropriate and change the parameter type, but not the implementation. In which case, you would be vulnerable. I like the `setInt` approach regardless because changing the ID parameter to String necessitates a change in the implementation, since `setInt` will fail to compile if the second argument is not an integer

Comment: its ok as long as its integer, but! some code analyzer may flag it as potential sql injection. it would be easier (for everyone) to stay consistent with parameterized sql rather than mixing string concat here and there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two things that might go wrong even if `id` is an int and can never be anything else:

1. Someone in the future might change the `id` type to a `String`.
2. Someone might copy-paste your code to another part of the codebase, and then modify the SQL so that it's concatenated with a `String`, making that part vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

The previous responses are correct - as a validated/typed int, this is likely not exploitable.  But it should be changed to future proof it and improve performance (the DB can cache the compiled statement more easily).

On a related note - although int is safe, real numbers and dates can be exploited in some cases via lateral SQL injection, even when those values have been fully validated or come from strong types.  This method uses the formatting mechanism for injection - see
http://www.davidlitchfield.com/Lateral_SQL_Injection_Revisited_Final.pdf .

Answer (score 0):

If your langage doesn't support strong typing or if input validation is weak, some malicious string (for example: "1 OR 1=1") can makes its way down to your request.

Comment: fyi its tagged as java, so its a strongly typed language.

Answer (score 0):

First Java is strongly typed language so, pragmatically speaking there is no way an sql injection make it to this part of code.

but security is more than that.
code quality is also a security level that is not to be taken lightly, if you pass this code snippet in a sonar qube server this will be revoqued.

Why ?

First if you r not respecting the string concatenation, this is not a performance freindly way of coding.

In large scale applications everything matters. where technical debt is also a vulnerablity